how to capture filename along with space in bash when operating with git diff
Team,
my use case is we don't want any user to push a file that has leading/trailing space in it. as it blocks windows local users
I have this code but seems like files_in_change=$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only) itself is stripping off the space which I don't want to happen. is there a way I can capture the filename as it is with space? when i am running the below script, I am never getting a failure though there exists a file in change that has space before/after.
#!/bin/sh

# For windows local users, check if each file in change has leading and trailing whitespace

# Fetch all affected files in change
files_in_change=$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only)
# Trim leading and trailing whitespace
trimmed_filename="${filename#"${filename%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
trimmed_filename="${trimmed_filename%"${trimmed_filename##*[![:space:]]}"}"

# Check if the original filename is different from the trimmed filename
if [ "$filename" != "$trimmed_filename" ]; then
    echo "Filename '$filename' has leading and/or trailing whitespace."
    # Block the change from merge as it blocks windows users local tests.
    exitcode=1
else
    exitcode=0
fi
exit $exitcode


To read the filenames into an array with all characters preserved exactly use  readarray -d '' files_in_change < <(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only -z).  To loop through the array use for filename in "${files_in_change[@]}"; do ....

the question has been tagged bash but the script's shebang is #!/bin/sh (not necessarily bash); please update the question to explicitly state the shell you're using

You set but never use files_in_change then you use but never set filename. Please always do what the [tag:bash] tag says and "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

(note that even when /bin/sh is a symlink to bash, bash runs in a compatibility mode with fewer features when started under the sh name).

Based on @pjh comment, and given the /bin/sh shebang, here's what you could do, as long as you have access to xargs -0 (which is most probably the case):
#!/bin/sh

git diff HEAD~1 --name-only -z |
xargs -0 awk '
    BEGIN {
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
            if ( ARGV[i] ~ /^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/ ) {
                print "Filename", shellquote(ARGV[i]), "has leading and/or trailing whitespace."
                rc = 1
            }
        exit rc
    }
    function shellquote(str) {
        gsub(/\047/,"\047\\\047\047",str);
        return "\047" str "\047";
    }
'


You can achieve the test with this simple script:
#/bin/sh

! git diff HEAD~1 --name-only |
grep --quiet -e '^[[:space:]]' -e '[[:space:]]$'

That is, use the exit code of grep --quiet (which must be GNU's grep) that tells whether one of the patterns was found. By using multiple expressions with -e, grep reports success when at least one of the patterns is found, but the leading ! tells to report success if no pattern was found.
To also write an error message, things become slightly more complicated. We just run the test twice in the case where there is an error:
#/bin/sh

if ! git diff HEAD~1 --name-only |
   grep --quiet -e '^[[:space:]]' -e '[[:space:]]$'
then
   exit 0
fi

echo "The following file names have leading or trailing spaces:"
git diff HEAD~1 --name-only |
   grep -e '^[[:space:]]' -e '[[:space:]]$'

exit 1

